# Object key as an arg in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to convert this code into typescript. Still pretty new, and I'm sure there's a trivial answer here.

The sticking point is that the key on the object should be able to take any possible value (and as an enhancement, maybe even a nested object, but that comes later).

How do I let TypeScript know allow an argument for a key that could hypothetically be any string?

```
// Creates an array of options.
// With current libs, it'll format to objects with this shape: {label: string; value: string}

// interface Option {
//   label: string;
//   value: string;
// }

export const createSelectOptions = (data, labelKey, valueKey) => {
  // const options = [] as Option[];
  const options = [];
  if (data) {
    data.forEach((el) => {
      options.push({ label: el[labelKey], value: el[valueKey] });
    });
  }
  return options;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* say that `data` has to be an array of objects with potential `string`-valued properties at *any* `string`-valued key; that is, `Array<Record<string, string>>` (using the built-in [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype))... well, and since you are checking it with `if (data)` I guess it could also be `null` or `undefined` or something falsy:

```
const createSelectOptionsMaybe = (
    data: Array<Record<string, string>> | null | undefined,
    labelKey: string,
    valueKey: string
) => {
    const options: Option[] = [];

    if (data) {
        data.forEach((el) => {
            options.push({ label: el[labelKey], value: el[valueKey] });
        });
    }
    return options;
};
```

And this would work for your presumably desired use case:

```
const optsMaybe = createSelectOptionsMaybe([
  { k: "a", v: "b" },
  { k: "c", v: "d" }
], "k", "v");

console.log(optsMaybe);
/* [{
  "label": "a",
  "value": "b"
}, {
  "label": "c",
  "value": "d"
}] */
```

Unfortunately, it would also "work" for undesirable calls:

```
const optsBad = createSelectOptionsMaybe([
    { a: "a", b: "b" }, { c: "c", d: "d" }
], "k", "v")
console.log(optsBad);
/* [{}, {}] ... uh oh */

optsBad.forEach(x => x.label.toUpperCase()); // compiles fine, but:    
// RUNTIME ERROR  x.label is undefined
```

Oops.

---

What you really want to say is that `data` is (if non-falsy) an array of objects whose keys *definitely include* the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) values passed in as the `labelKey` and `valueKey` parameters.  It's not just "any `string`", it's "the specific `string` values passed in".  For that, you need a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function.

We'll think of `createSelectOptions()` as being generic in `K`, a type parameter that is assignable to `string`, intended to be the union of the types of `labelKey` and `valueKey`:

```
const createSelectOptions = <K extends string>(
    data: Array<Record<K, string>> | null | undefined,
    labelKey: K,
    valueKey: K
) => {
    const options: Option[] = [];

    if (data) {
        data.forEach((el) => {
            options.push({ label: el[labelKey], value: el[valueKey] });
        });
    }
    return options;
};
```

This works just the same for the desirable use cases:

```
const opts = createSelectOptions([{ k: "a", v: "b" }, { k: "c", v: "d" }], "k", "v");

console.log(opts);
/* [{
  "label": "a",
  "value": "b"
}, {
  "label": "c",
  "value": "d"
}] */
```

And you can see that `K` is inferred above as the union `"k" | "v"`:

```
/* const createSelectOptions: <"k" | "v">(
    data: Record<"k" | "v", string>[] | null | undefined, 
    labelKey: "k" | "v", 
    valueKey: "k" | "v") => Option[] */
```

And now the undesirable call from before produces compiler warnings, because the compiler expects `data`'s elements to have keys `"k"` and `"v"`, which they don't:

```
createSelectOptions([
    { a: "a", b: "b" }, // error!
    // Type '{ a: string; b: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"k" | "v", string>'.
    { c: "c", d: "d" }, // error!
    // Type '{ c: string; d: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"k" | "v", string>'.
], "k", "v")
```

Great!  It is still possible to circumvent this protection, namely by causing `K` to be inferred or by specifying it manually as `string`, which falls back to the earlier behavior:

```
createSelectOptions<string>([
    { a: "a", b: "b" }, 
    { c: "c", d: "d" },
], "k", "v") // no error now
```

But it's less likely for this to happen accidentally, at least.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwFgAoZM5AGzgCMIKAuZAZzClAHMBuE85ANzgUArhEYs2ILiQC+JEglwtkCKBDiQAynQgIwGLIoCycAJ61kAXmQAKHuQAm6uIwCCUKKYA8AJR3Yo9p7iHAA0zKwcAHyRyAA+yCBCFBRxyEIg9hAwoBD2IXZkVLQUANIQJmIRkvmk5ALCEGUV4RLsJACUljFEtWQKIErYmDgDjPojANoAupbI09zEBcjAMDaOYHCdPby863AAdDD+AKKIABbW1nSdFt1LO+RDBgP76EJMF-iUNHSMdBNFOhNKZheoiP4UCZgxrlGbSdoLB5keGI8iyXrIVRgIRQPBPEZMBbSBbyRRgZBPJjGMwoKwqNSabS6cZGUy0awTJZfADWjAARHA+aD+dQ+chpDVeDz+Qghfx+fYxeiQcg+dy5Xy+HyEXJiP0mNgKBB9hRsOxrJTqbQdcQAPQAKjm21VgIofP5gslquh7tVopkYWdfNdvr5sq9msEIlDipkM3ttt1+vJlIAQnB7LN6eoIFojczhqyaRyuchnKrPchqCKlYHlDK5fYFUqSCq1Rqte1SQNDcbTea0xmbQ6nRKCNIZvsp2kzhTZwmSKwTAQloP7IcTudrAAPLrIbcmn4UfZgbAAVXQ6GgAGE4EwINZ2gjkLbbcpsABbdDAI1MZDZEAIDCaghDARhyBkZR1AQWcri2JZ9V7E0zTgzgXzfbwzwAOQAFQASUMY5kGObxvFQbxkEAXg3AFKd-dD2KZY-3STIANyGRdW7JRs0ZfM9ELAZZk8EpkAgbdIAyP9gkkSJbAxPZXHcLxfAUAIhLCKT2GiVJEmSVJmKyHI8iWV0mkYEovTIaFTOQEoOj3Z0+jJCl+KYMZ+OmWZ5l1XgVjWJx4IxXYnA3KBThgy5rns+4kXxRRXneT5vmKCEASPYFQSjUQRMhKzYXFG0kXy1FkSWLEcTxFyiRJPUnMpLNVBzPMdD454mA5aUKzlPga3FOteVVcN5VVRVxTbdUwk1bUFhHZNlAanjmpZUZkE8dtUkmmSlnk5BlP8QI1viSb1KqTSPPiHSUnifTWLyZBjLS8p+XVdatTCJZcuaA7vW1Pclo8hdFhqnsjWQgdMCYYdHQmIMQw9IU7EjBpQ39Ygxxho9Q3DBGfWbONkAB+R5tzJkWoJEsMS+csBTlas-VrdCRPcfwAEIllfZAcJMK9kAAckpypWjQ2mNLQ6QecYhJsHJO8mGAdgQBoI1kFPZWuZQHndtUr6jpaKIef2UsEAbMIm2G+n2egKAWbZt9Oe5vn611yQ0NNkXxXF4A-xAKWyyYWX5cVlAVbANXec1-bnsO16nc0-XWwm8bvq7QHuOJ3ilqYIITpkzkKbLOHgJ6sdDeN5BTb5EaJXj1VE8mzp2e9xmragSWAHcSCAA)

Comment: So I got this error with your code: 

  Type 'CommuteTimes[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>[]'.
    Type 'CommuteTimes' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.

the interface for CommuteTimes is : interface CommuteTimes {
  id: string;
  duration: number;
  locationId: string;
  employeeId: string;
  locationName: string;
}


Would I need to reformat these values in order to use this? Because the idea is to feed in interfaces like that into this function, ideally.

Comment: I pretty much need a [mcve], preferably with a link to this in an IDE like [this](https://tsplay.dev/KN7EGW).  If you want to do this in comments you could use https://tsplay.dev/; otherwise you should edit your question to provide enough detail.  It is true that interfaces do not get implicit index signatures, so you'd want to use the generic version I guess.  But without a [mcve] I'm just kind of shrugging here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first letting typescript know the shape of the data. (I assume it is an array of objects that can be indexed by both the labelKey and the valueKey)

We can do this with generic types:

```js
export function createSelectOptions<T extends { [key: string]: string }>(
    data: T[] | undefined,
    labelKey: keyof T,
    valueKey: keyof T
): Option[] {
    const options: Option[] = [];

    if (data) {
        data.forEach((el) => {
            options.push({ label: el[labelKey], value: el[valueKey] });
        });
    }

    return options;
}
```

Here we are saying that there is one main type involved, `T` (the type of our elements `el`), which is an object with keys specified by strings. (you could change this to `number` or `string | number` if the `el` will be indexed by different things) We declare `T` in the triangle brackets after the function name.

It seems from your implementation that the `data` object may be `undefined`, so we can add that. If it IS defined, then it is an array of elements of type `T`.

In typescript we can use the `keyof` key word to name a type that is a key of a given object. ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) is an explanation in the typescript docs) We can type both labelKey and valueKey accordingly.